# email alerts for Azure Logic app runs failed

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I want an email notification for every logic app run with Failed status like below screenshot.
[image]

I tried to configure Runs Failed alerts in logic app but things are not very clear to me.
what should be the excect entry for **Threshold value, Operator , aggression type, Period and frequency** to get alert notification on every failed run.
[image]

Comment: As it is in your picture, the rule will be evaluated every 5 minutes, and the rule will check whether there has been more than 1 failure in the preceding 24 hours.  Perhaps you want to reduce the aggregation period.  However even on failure the static results is null, so perhaps this will never alert.

Comment: @karora so aggregation 5-minute and frequency 5 minute will work right?

Comment: Hi @RohitChouhan In the solution I provided below, I think 5 minutes is a good setup (because when I test with 1 minutes, it sends the trigger notification and then sends the resolve notification after about 3 minutes, so I don't think 1 minutes will work very well). But if you want to receive the notification as soon as possible, you can also set a smaller minutes.

Comment: Hi @RohitChouhan May I know if your alert works fine ? If it works without any problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Comment: @HuryShen yesh its working fine, yes sure...thanks

Comment: @RohitChouhan, if in case you are finding difficult to provision monitors in the portal, I would suggest looking at Serverless360 monitors (Threshold, Data, Status, Watch) to configure the desired metrics at a go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this requirement, I think you can choose `Static` in "**Threshold**" and set condition as `Great than Count 0`. In "**Evaluated based on**", you can set 5 minutes as "**Aggregation granularity (Period)**" and set 5 minutes as "**Frequency of evaluation**". Shown as below screenshot:

[image]

The "**Evaluated based on**" you choose as 24hours and every 5 minutes is not particularly good. Because once the alert triggered, its "Monitor condition" will become "fired", and if it hasn't been solved, the alert will not be triggered again.(For example, your logic failed on 1:00, the alert will be triggered in 5 minutes. But it will not be triggered again if there is a failure during the last 24 hour when evaluate every 5 minutes).

By the way, you can also test it by yourself. You can create a logic app as below, it is allowed to be saved and will fail when run it.

[image]